Setup Jaeger in docker-compose - not with all-in-one image
I want a solution in a docker-compose file. I took this docker-compose file and this one.
I came up with the following, but there is an issue with the services communicating with the Jaeger collector.
traces export: context deadline exceeded: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp 172.18.0.10:4317: connect: connection refused"
version: '3'
services:
  service-a:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: service-a/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - service-jaeger
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - OUTBOUND_HOST_PORT=service-b:8082
      - OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://jaeger-collector:4317
      - OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_INSECURE=true

  service-b:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: service-b/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - service-jaeger
    environment:
      - OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://jaeger-collector:4317
      - OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_INSECURE=true

  # Using ElasticSearch as a storage for traces and logs
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.11.3
    networks:
      - service-jaeger
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2g -Xmx2g"
      - "bootstrap.memory_lock=true"
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      - "xpack.security.enabled=false"
      - "xpack.security.enrollment.enabled=false"
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:9200:9200"
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536

  # Using Apache Kafka as a temporary storage and stream processing system (span post processing)
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.2.1
    networks:
      - service-jaeger
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
    restart: on-failure

  # Using Apache Zookeeper to coordenate Apache services
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.2.1
    networks:
      - service-jaeger
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: "2181"

  # Using Jaeger Collector to receive spans from Jaeger Agents and send them to Kafka
  jaeger-collector:
    image: jaegertracing/jaeger-collector:1.11.0
    hostname: jaeger-collector
    ports:
      - "14269:14269"
      - "14268:14268"
      - "14267:14267"
      - "9411:9411"
    networks:
      - service-jaeger
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      LOG_LEVEL: "info"
      SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE: "kafka"
      KAFKA_BROKERS: "kafka:9092"
      METRICS_BACKEND: "prometheus"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  # Using Jaeger Ingester to receive spans from Kafka and send them to ElasticSearch
  jaeger-ingester:
    image: jaegertracing/jaeger-ingester:1.11.0
    networks:
      - service-jaeger
    ports:
      - "14270:14270"
      - "14271:14271"
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      LOG_LEVEL: "info"
      INGESTER_PARALLELISM: "1"
      INGESTER_DEADLOCKINTERVAL: "0ms"
      SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE: "elasticsearch"
      ES_SERVER_URLS: "http://elasticsearch:9200"
      KAFKA_BROKERS: "kafka:9092"
      METRICS_BACKEND: "prometheus"
    depends_on:
      - kafka

  # Using Jaeger Agent to receive spans from clients locally and send to remote Jaeger Collector
  jaeger-agent:
    image: jaegertracing/jaeger-agent:1.11.0
    hostname: jaeger-agent
    command: ["--collector.host-port=jaeger-collector:14267"]
    ports:
      - "5775:5775/udp"
      - "6831:6831/udp"
      - "6832:6832/udp"
      - "5778:5778"
    networks:
      - service-jaeger
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE: "elasticsearch"
      METRICS_BACKEND: "prometheus"
    depends_on:
      - jaeger-collector

  #
  # USER INTERFACES
  #

  # Using Jaeger Query to work with traces
  jaeger-query:
    image: jaegertracing/jaeger-query:1.11.0
    environment:
      SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE: "elasticsearch"
      no_proxy: "localhost"
      METRICS_BACKEND: "prometheus"
    ports:
      - "16686:16686"
      - "16687:16687"
    networks:
      - service-jaeger
    restart: on-failure
    command: [
      "--es.server-urls=http://elasticsearch:9200",
      "--span-storage.type=elasticsearch",
      "--log-level=debug",
      "--query.ui-config=/usr/share/jaeger-query/jaeger-query-config.json"
    ]
    volumes:
      - ./jaeger-query-config.json:/usr/share/jaeger-query/jaeger-query-config.json:ro
    depends_on:
      - jaeger-agent

volumes:
  esdata:

networks:
  service-jaeger:
    driver: bridge


The config is specifying OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT but never mentions which type of exporter to use (e.g. OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER)

@YuriShkuro - there is a default value for this key - otlp

You need to use a newer jaeger-collector image. In the container logs for jaeger-collector:1.11.0, it shows that the collector starts a gRPC server listening on port 14250, not on port 4317. And if OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT is changed to http://jaeger-collector:14250, a different error traces export: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service opentelemetry.proto.collector.trace.v1.TraceService occurs.
jaeger-collector:1.11.0 logs:
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715817606.124311,"caller":"healthcheck/handler.go:99","msg":"Health Check server started","http-port":14269,"status":"unavailable"}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | WARNING: found deprecated option kafka.brokers, please use kafka.producer.brokers instead
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715817606.1347585,"caller":"kafka/factory.go:62","msg":"Kafka factory","producer builder":{"Brokers":["kafka:9092"]},"topic":"jaeger-spans"}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715817606.1638942,"caller":"static/strategy_store.go:79","msg":"No sampling strategies provided, using defaults"}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715817606.170055,"caller":"collector/main.go:140","msg":"Starting jaeger-collector TChannel server","port":14267}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715817606.1706026,"caller":"grpcserver/grpc_server.go:64","msg":"Starting jaeger-collector gRPC server","grpc-port":"14250"}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715817606.1713939,"caller":"collector/main.go:154","msg":"Registering metrics handler with HTTP server","route":"/metrics"}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715817606.1718876,"caller":"collector/main.go:163","msg":"Starting jaeger-collector HTTP server","http-port":14268}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715817606.1722622,"caller":"healthcheck/handler.go:133","msg":"Health Check state change","status":"ready"}

Once the collector is upgraded to the latest version, 1.57, this error goes away as the newer version creates a otlpreceiver gRPC server listening on port 4317. And from the kafka container logs, I could see messages being published to jaeger-spans topic.
jaeger-collector:1.57 logs:
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | 2024/05/16 00:41:06 maxprocs: Leaving GOMAXPROCS=8: CPU quota undefined
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | 2024/05/16 00:41:06 application version: git-commit=55e991a29725468164b11be5fc4e260dc09598d6, git-version=v1.57.0, build-date=2024-05-01T23:19:12Z
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715820066.9970202,"caller":"flags/service.go:110","msg":"Mounting metrics handler on admin server","route":"/metrics"}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715820066.9974976,"caller":"flags/service.go:116","msg":"Mounting expvar handler on admin server","route":"/debug/vars"}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715820066.9984624,"caller":"flags/admin.go:130","msg":"Mounting health check on admin server","route":"/"}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715820066.9987607,"caller":"flags/admin.go:144","msg":"Starting admin HTTP server","http-addr":":14269"}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715820067.0008337,"caller":"flags/admin.go:122","msg":"Admin server started","http.host-port":"[::]:14269","health-status":"unavailable"}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715820067.0110576,"caller":"kafka/factory.go:77","msg":"Kafka factory","producer builder":{"Brokers":["kafka:9092"],"RequiredAcks":1,"Compression":"none","CompressionLevel":0,"ProtocolVersion":"","BatchLinger":0,"BatchSize":0,"BatchMinMessages":0,"BatchMaxMessages":0,"MaxMessageBytes":1000000,"Authentication":"none","Kerberos":{"ServiceName":"kafka","Realm":"","UseKeyTab":false,"Username":"","ConfigPath":"/etc/krb5.conf","KeyTabPath":"/etc/security/kafka.keytab","DisablePAFXFast":false},"TLS":{"Enabled":false,"CAPath":"","CertPath":"","KeyPath":"","ServerName":"","ClientCAPath":"","CipherSuites":null,"MinVersion":"","MaxVersion":"","SkipHostVerify":false,"ReloadInterval":0},"PlainText":{"Username":"","Mechanism":"PLAIN"}},"topic":"jaeger-spans"}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715820067.0482032,"caller":"static/strategy_store.go:68","msg":"No sampling strategies source provided, using defaults"}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715820067.085572,"caller":"grpc@v1.63.2/server.go:675","msg":"[core][Server #1]Server created","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715820067.0860224,"caller":"server/grpc.go:104","msg":"Starting jaeger-collector gRPC server","grpc.host-port":"[::]:14250"}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715820067.0860848,"caller":"server/http.go:56","msg":"Starting jaeger-collector HTTP server","http host-port":":14268"}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715820067.0868862,"caller":"grpc@v1.63.2/server.go:871","msg":"[core][Server #1 ListenSocket #2]ListenSocket created","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715820067.0912595,"caller":"app/collector.go:146","msg":"Not listening for Zipkin HTTP traffic, port not configured"}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715820067.091624,"caller":"handler/otlp_receiver.go:77","msg":"OTLP receiver status change","status":"StatusStarting"}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"warn","ts":1715820067.091747,"caller":"internal@v0.98.0/warning.go:42","msg":"Using the 0.0.0.0 address exposes this server to every network interface, which may facilitate Denial of Service attacks. Enable the feature gate to change the default and remove this warning.","documentation":"https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/docs/security-best-practices.md#safeguards-against-denial-of-service-attacks","feature gate ID":"component.UseLocalHostAsDefaultHost"}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715820067.09237,"caller":"grpc@v1.63.2/server.go:675","msg":"[core][Server #3]Server created","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715820067.0924554,"caller":"otlpreceiver@v0.98.0/otlp.go:102","msg":"Starting GRPC server","endpoint":"0.0.0.0:4317"}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"warn","ts":1715820067.1029644,"caller":"internal@v0.98.0/warning.go:42","msg":"Using the 0.0.0.0 address exposes this server to every network interface, which may facilitate Denial of Service attacks. Enable the feature gate to change the default and remove this warning.","documentation":"https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/docs/security-best-practices.md#safeguards-against-denial-of-service-attacks","feature gate ID":"component.UseLocalHostAsDefaultHost"}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715820067.1030934,"caller":"otlpreceiver@v0.98.0/otlp.go:152","msg":"Starting HTTP server","endpoint":"0.0.0.0:4318"}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715820067.1046698,"caller":"healthcheck/handler.go:129","msg":"Health Check state change","status":"ready"}
jaeger-go-example-jaeger-collector-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1715820067.1038973,"caller":"grpc@v1.63.2/server.go:871","msg":"[core][Server #3 ListenSocket #4]ListenSocket created","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}

Minimal docker-compose.yml:
services:
  # Using Apache Zookeeper to co-ordinate Apache services
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.2.1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: "2181"
    

  # Using Apache Kafka as a temporary storage and stream processing system (span post processing)
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.2.1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9093:9093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:9092,EXTERNAL://:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    healthcheck:
      test: nc -z localhost 9092 || exit -1
      start_period: 15s
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10

  jaeger-collector:
    image: jaegertracing/jaeger-collector:1.57
    hostname: jaeger-collector
    ports:
      - "14269:14269"
      - "14268:14268"
      - "14267:14267"
      - "9411:9411"
    environment:
      LOG_LEVEL: "info"
      SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE: "kafka"
      KAFKA_PRODUCER_BROKERS: "kafka:9092"
      METRICS_BACKEND: "prometheus"
    depends_on:
      kafka:
        condition: service_healthy

  service-b:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: service-b/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://jaeger-collector:4317
      - OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_INSECURE=true
    ports:
      - '8082:8082'
    depends_on:
      - jaeger-collector


Thanks! I added a gist to add the Jaeger Query UI as well - https://gist.github.com/bdparrish/884f0b213c429c9967d48d5b3d1cb746

You aren't mapping 4317 anywhere that I can see (add -p 4317:4317). Also, you have to enable OLTP on the collector  -e COLLECTOR_OTLP_ENABLED=true.  Add a depends_on entry for jaeger-collector in your service-a and service-b definitions, this will ensure that the collector comes up first.
Why aren't you using something else to manage Kafka versus just doing it this way in a container? Kafka without any redundancy is not the best idea.

-e COLLECTOR_OTLP_ENABLED=true is not needed since last year, it's the default.

you don't need to map 4317 to the host machine since it is exposed in the Dockerfile and therefore available on the Docker network that was setup.

Sorry if its wrong. But I don't know how you expose the 4317 port in your Dockerfile.
Remember that EXPOSE in Dockerfile is mostly for documentation purpose and has no real purpose. You need to have the service in the container listen on port 4317 and expose that like this.
ports:
 - "4317:4317"


See the comment below - https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#expose - TL:DR; the EXPOSE command lets other containers on the docker network reach the service on this port.
